# Visual Studio Templates with NuGet Dependencies that depend on other NuGet packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, vsix

I created a project template that I will distribute as a VSIX. The template depends on a NuGet package (that I've created), I followed the steps described here https://docs.nuget.org/create/packages-in-visual-studio-templates#vsix-package-repository This sort of works, it creates a project and applies the NuGet, but it doesn't apply the dependencies of this NuGet (eg: JQuery, bootstrap...)

A restore doesn't do the trick either. Any thoughts ?

thanks

Comment: do some error appear? what's the excat problem...

Comment: No error appears, but I can see that for example the references are missing. My package depends on jQuery, but there is no scripts folder created , although the folders my package creates are there.

Comment: ok, got that... worth upvoting

Answer (score -2):

```
Have done the following config 

<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages repository="extension" repositoryId="your vsix id">
      <package id="your package" version="1.0.0" />
     </packages>
  </WizardData
```